# Load Function on start of Form

Tags: winforms, powershell

I would like to know how I can load a function when form is started?

In this example I would like to launch the function `test()` which adds a line to the RichTextBox. I don't want a button and when I try `$form1.Show` the form doesn't work.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'

Function test {
  $richtextbox1.AppendText("testttt `n")
}

function CreateForm {
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

  $form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

  #Form Parameter
  $form1.Text = ""
  $form1.Name = ""
  $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
  $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 600
  $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 500
  $form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
  $Form1.MinimizeBox = $false
  $Form1.MaximizeBox = $true
  $form1.ControlBox = $true
  $form1.Topmost = $true
  $Form1.AutoSize = $true
  $Form1.ShowInTaskbar = $false
  $form1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

  $label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200, 40)
  $label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 40)
  $label1.Text = ""
  $label1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
  $form1.Controls.Add($label1)

  $label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50, 125)
  $label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 40)
  $label2.Text = "Step : "
  $label2.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
  $form1.Controls.Add($label2)

  $label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50, 175)
  $label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 40)
  $label3.Text = " in Progress"
  $label3.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
  $form1.Controls.Add($label3)

  $richTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
  $richTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50, 250)
  $richTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500, 200)
  $richTextBox1.Text = " : `n"
  $richTextBox1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
  $form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox1)

  $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
  #Show the Form

  $form1.ShowDialog()
  test
}

CreateForm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CreateForm`-function will freeze on `$form1.ShowDialog()` until the form is closed, so `test` will never run. What you can do is add `test` as an eventhandler to the [Shown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx)-event that is trigged on the first launch of a form.

Replace:

```
$form1.ShowDialog()
test
```

with:

```
$form1.add_Shown({ test } )
$form1.ShowDialog()
```

You can also run the function before showing the dialog since it only modifies the form anyways (or just do the modifications directly in the form-code):

```
test
$form1.ShowDialog()
```